# comparing mongo collection data with mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb

I have some data in mongo db and this cannot be stored in mysql as it is unstructured data. The collection is somewhat bigger and mostly contains email related information like email ID and events. Now I have another table in mysql which stores the user information. So I need to cross compare the email IDs and need to fetch some of user details like joining date for the mail IDs in mongo collection. Is there any method to do it other than looping through each of the mail IDs and fetching the specific row from MySQL ? I need to dump these data to CSV and so I am pulling the data without limits. If both the tables are in mysql, I can appy joins here.

Comment: I cannot just understand your requirement.Why not just store all the data into mongodb?For every user ,store the email ID and the user infomation into one single document .

Comment: it is like that only. I am using sendgrid event api to get the notifications for emails and newsletters. So it is posting data back to my server on every second and I am stroing this in mongo as the data is unstructured and in JSON format. Now just need to populate reports whith the comparison